# How to print words from object to specified position in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have object in javascript and keys of the object are words of my paragraph how to print it in paragraph.Value(key:value) holds its position.

Tried using for loop to fetch didnt work for me

```
var userdata= {
          "\"Ten": [
            0
          ],
          "blue": [
            1
          ],
          "links\"": [
            2
          ],
          "have": [
            3
          ],
          "defined": [
            4
          ],
          "web": [
            5,
            36,
            65
          ],
          "search": [
            6,
            32,
            37,
            70,
            90,
            108,
            126
          ],
          "results": [
            7,
            33,
            38,
            71,
            82,
            99,
            119
          ],
          "for": [
            8,
            80
          ],
          "the": [
            9,
            28,
            56,
            61,
            69,
            95,
            105
          ],
          "last": [
            10
          ],
          "fifteen": [
            11
          ],
          "years": [
            12
          ],
          "--": [
            13
          ],
          "snippets": [
            14
          ],
          "of": [
            15,
            30,
            63,
            97,
            107,
            125
          ],
          "text": [
            16
          ],
          "combined": [
            17
          ],
          "with": [
            18,
            60
          ],
          "document": [
            19
          ],
          "titles": [
            20
          ],
          "and": [
            21,
            46,
            52,
            85
          ],
          "URLs.": [
            22
          ],
          "In": [
            23
          ],
          "this": [
            24
          ],
          "paper,": [
            25
          ],
          "we": [
            26,
            111,
            114
          ],
          "establish": [
            27
          ],
          "notion": [
            29
          ],
          "enhanced": [
            31,
            81,
            98,
            118
          ],
          "that": [
            34,
            54,
            75,
            113
          ],
          "extend": [
            35
          ],
          "to": [
            39,
            58,
            103,
            120
          ],
          "include": [
            40
          ],
          "multimedia": [
            41
          ],
          "objects": [
            42
          ],
          "such": [
            43
          ],
          "as": [
            44
          ],
          "images": [
            45
          ],
          "video,": [
            47
          ],
          "intent-specific": [
            48
          ],
          "key": [
            49
          ],
          "value": [
            50
          ],
          "pairs,": [
            51
          ],
          "elements": [
            53
          ],
          "allow": [
            55
          ],
          "user": [
            57
          ],
          "interact": [
            59
          ],
          "contents": [
            62
          ],
          "a": [
            64,
            78,
            122
          ],
          "page": [
            66
          ],
          "directly": [
            67
          ],
          "from": [
            68
          ],
          "page.": [
            72
          ],
          "We": [
            73,
            92
          ],
          "show": [
            74,
            112
          ],
          "users": [
            76,
            102
          ],
          "express": [
            77
          ],
          "preference": [
            79
          ],
          "both": [
            83
          ],
          "explicitly,": [
            84
          ],
          "when": [
            86
          ],
          "observed": [
            87
          ],
          "in": [
            88,
            100
          ],
          "their": [
            89
          ],
          "behavior.": [
            91
          ],
          "also": [
            93
          ],
          "demonstrate": [
            94
          ],
          "effectiveness": [
            96
          ],
          "helping": [
            101
          ],
          "assess": [
            104
          ],
          "relevance": [
            106
          ],
          "results.": [
            109
          ],
          "Lastly,": [
            110
          ],
          "can": [
            115
          ],
          "efficiently": [
            116
          ],
          "generate": [
            117
          ],
          "cover": [
            121
          ],
          "significant": [
            123
          ],
          "fraction": [
            124
          ],
          "result": [
            127
          ],
          "pages.": [
            128
          ]
        };
```

> "Ten blue links" have defined web search results for the last fifteen years -- snippets of text combined with document titles and URLs. In this paper, we establish the notion of enhanced search results that extend web search results to include multimedia objects such as images and video, intent-specific key value pairs, and elements that allow the user to interact with the contents of a web page directly from the search results page. We show that users express a preference for enhanced results both explicitly, and when observed in their search behavior. We also demonstrate the effectiveness of enhanced results in helping users to assess the relevance of search results. Lastly, we show that we can efficiently generate enhanced results to cover a significant fraction of search result pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the object to word/indexes pair with `Object.entries()`. Iterate the entries using `Array.reduce()`. Inside the reduce, iterate the indexes with `Array.forEach()`, and assign each word to its index in the accumulator (`r`). Join the the array of words with a space.

```js
const userdata = {"\"Ten":[0],"blue":[1],"links\"":[2],"have":[3],"defined":[4],"web":[5,36,65],"search":[6,32,37,70,90,108,126],"results":[7,33,38,71,82,99,119],"for":[8,80],"the":[9,28,56,61,69,95,105],"last":[10],"fifteen":[11],"years":[12],"--":[13],"snippets":[14],"of":[15,30,63,97,107,125],"text":[16],"combined":[17],"with":[18,60],"document":[19],"titles":[20],"and":[21,46,52,85],"URLs.":[22],"In":[23],"this":[24],"paper,":[25],"we":[26,111,114],"establish":[27],"notion":[29],"enhanced":[31,81,98,118],"that":[34,54,75,113],"extend":[35],"to":[39,58,103,120],"include":[40],"multimedia":[41],"objects":[42],"such":[43],"as":[44],"images":[45],"video,":[47],"intent-specific":[48],"key":[49],"value":[50],"pairs,":[51],"elements":[53],"allow":[55],"user":[57],"interact":[59],"contents":[62],"a":[64,78,122],"page":[66],"directly":[67],"from":[68],"page.":[72],"We":[73,92],"show":[74,112],"users":[76,102],"express":[77],"preference":[79],"both":[83],"explicitly,":[84],"when":[86],"observed":[87],"in":[88,100],"their":[89],"behavior.":[91],"also":[93],"demonstrate":[94],"effectiveness":[96],"helping":[101],"assess":[104],"relevance":[106],"results.":[109],"Lastly,":[110],"can":[115],"efficiently":[116],"generate":[117],"cover":[121],"significant":[123],"fraction":[124],"result":[127],"pages.":[128]};

const result = Object.entries(userdata)
  .reduce((r, [word, indexes]) => {
    indexes.forEach(index => r[index] = word);
    
    return r;
  }, [])
  .join(' ');
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I stole the inlined array from your answer to avoid having so much lines, I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: That's fine. Standard practice :) It's easy to create it - in the chrome console - `copy(JSON.stringify(targetArrayOrObject))`.

Comment: ah converting to json string, that's clever

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through that object and

- get the key name (`word`)
- use the provided positions (`index`) from `userdata[word]`
- define in a result array the index and word to use, such as `arrResult[index] = word`.

And then, join that array in a string using `' '` as delimiter

In example :

```js
var userdata = {"\"Ten":[0],"blue":[1],"links\"":[2],"have":[3],"defined":[4],"web":[5,36,65],"search":[6,32,37,70,90,108,126],"results":[7,33,38,71,82,99,119],"for":[8,80],"the":[9,28,56,61,69,95,105],"last":[10],"fifteen":[11],"years":[12],"--":[13],"snippets":[14],"of":[15,30,63,97,107,125],"text":[16],"combined":[17],"with":[18,60],"document":[19],"titles":[20],"and":[21,46,52,85],"URLs.":[22],"In":[23],"this":[24],"paper,":[25],"we":[26,111,114],"establish":[27],"notion":[29],"enhanced":[31,81,98,118],"that":[34,54,75,113],"extend":[35],"to":[39,58,103,120],"include":[40],"multimedia":[41],"objects":[42],"such":[43],"as":[44],"images":[45],"video,":[47],"intent-specific":[48],"key":[49],"value":[50],"pairs,":[51],"elements":[53],"allow":[55],"user":[57],"interact":[59],"contents":[62],"a":[64,78,122],"page":[66],"directly":[67],"from":[68],"page.":[72],"We":[73,92],"show":[74,112],"users":[76,102],"express":[77],"preference":[79],"both":[83],"explicitly,":[84],"when":[86],"observed":[87],"in":[88,100],"their":[89],"behavior.":[91],"also":[93],"demonstrate":[94],"effectiveness":[96],"helping":[101],"assess":[104],"relevance":[106],"results.":[109],"Lastly,":[110],"can":[115],"efficiently":[116],"generate":[117],"cover":[121],"significant":[123],"fraction":[124],"result":[127],"pages.":[128]};

let arrResult = [];

for (let word in userdata)
{
  userdata[word].forEach((i) =>
  {
    arrResult[i] = word;
  });
}
let result = arrResult.join(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your data is the property name itself, so, the easiest way is to get that names with:

```
var foo = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(userdata);
```

That function returns you all the property names of the object in an array, so you simply join it:

```
foo.join(" ");
```

Hope it suits for you.

---

EDIT

The above code is not a functional solution in this case, didn't consider the words' index. So the correct way to aproach the solution whould be something like Cid's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474582/9925983):

```js
const userdata = {"\"Ten":[0],"blue":[1],"links\"":[2],"have":[3],"defined":[4],"web":[5,36,65],"search":[6,32,37,70,90,108,126],"results":[7,33,38,71,82,99,119],"for":[8,80],"the":[9,28,56,61,69,95,105],"last":[10],"fifteen":[11],"years":[12],"--":[13],"snippets":[14],"of":[15,30,63,97,107,125],"text":[16],"combined":[17],"with":[18,60],"document":[19],"titles":[20],"and":[21,46,52,85],"URLs.":[22],"In":[23],"this":[24],"paper,":[25],"we":[26,111,114],"establish":[27],"notion":[29],"enhanced":[31,81,98,118],"that":[34,54,75,113],"extend":[35],"to":[39,58,103,120],"include":[40],"multimedia":[41],"objects":[42],"such":[43],"as":[44],"images":[45],"video,":[47],"intent-specific":[48],"key":[49],"value":[50],"pairs,":[51],"elements":[53],"allow":[55],"user":[57],"interact":[59],"contents":[62],"a":[64,78,122],"page":[66],"directly":[67],"from":[68],"page.":[72],"We":[73,92],"show":[74,112],"users":[76,102],"express":[77],"preference":[79],"both":[83],"explicitly,":[84],"when":[86],"observed":[87],"in":[88,100],"their":[89],"behavior.":[91],"also":[93],"demonstrate":[94],"effectiveness":[96],"helping":[101],"assess":[104],"relevance":[106],"results.":[109],"Lastly,":[110],"can":[115],"efficiently":[116],"generate":[117],"cover":[121],"significant":[123],"fraction":[124],"result":[127],"pages.":[128]};

let words = [];

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(userdata).forEach(propertyName =>
  userdata[propertyName].forEach(value => words[value] = propertyName)
);

const text = words.join(' ');
console.log(text);
```

His answer still being more readable and efficient in my opinion.

Comment: Yeh, missunderstood the question, forgot about those index values tho, so doesn't work unless all words are in the object.@OliverRadini.